# Pound sign # in title creates error with htlatex and make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

If I try to typeset the following minimal working example with `latex`, no errors occur:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{\#}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

However if I try to typset it with either `htlatex` or `make4ht`, I get the errors

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \:temp.
```

and

```
You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
Illegal parameter number in definition of \:temp.
```

respectively.

**What's the problem and how do I fix it?**

*Edit: It seems I can simply avoid this issue by using `latexml` (which seems more robust and up-to-date and produces better output), however I would still like to know what's causing the error here and how to make `htlatex` and `make4ht` work.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take care of this issue in TeX4ht sources. In the meantime, you can use the following configuration file (using trick from David's answer):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\DeclareRobustCommand\myhash{\symbol{35}}
\Configure{TITLE+}{\myhash}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Configure{TITLE+}` command sets contents of the `<title>` tag, so you can use it every time you have something in your title that fails.

This is the result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head> <title>#</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='sample.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='sample.tex' name='src' /> 
</head><body>
   <div class='maketitle'>



<h2 class='titleHead'>#</h2>
<div class='author'></div><br />
<div class='date'><span class='cmr-12'>March 29, 2022</span></div>
   </div>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: So it's a bug after all. If you fix it, I'd be interested to hear what caused this issue.

Comment: The bug was caused by the fact that the `#` character was written to an auxiliary file, which is loaded at the beginning of the document. It causes the compilation error. With the patch, `\#` is written instead, so it works when aux file is loaded.